# What is the PSTricks equivalent for 'turn' in Tikz?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=15pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\def\a{3}
\draw[step=1,thin,gray!50] (0,0) grid (4*\a,2*\a);%Vẽ lưới
\draw (0:0)--++(90:1.5*\a)coordinate(A)--([turn]-159:\a)coordinate(B)--([turn]120:\a)coordinate(C)--(A);
\draw(B)--(C)--([turn]-125:\a)coordinate(D)--([turn]90:\a)coordinate(E)--([turn]90:\a)coordinate(F)--(C);
\draw(D)--(E)--([turn]-37:\a)coordinate(G)--([turn]72:\a)coordinate(H)--([turn]72:\a)coordinate(I)--([turn]72:\a)coordinate(J)--(E);
\draw (G)--(H)--([turn]-141:\a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My PSTricks's code

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\def\a{3}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(15,10)
\psline(0,0)(+0,1.5*\a)
\pnode(+0,1.5*\a){A} \uput[90](A){$A$}
\rput(A){%
\pnode(\a;-69){B} \uput[-90](B){$B$}
\pnode(\a;-9){C} \uput[90](C){$C$}
}
%
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=55]{B}C){D}
\uput[-90](D){$D$}
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=145]{B}C){F}
\uput[90](F){$F$}
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=90]{C}F){E}
\uput[-90](E){$E$}
%
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=143]{D}E){G}
\uput[-90](G){$G$}
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=108]{G}E){J}
\uput[120](J){$J$}
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=108]{E}J){I}
\uput[90](I){$I$}
\pnode([nodesep=\a,angle=108]{J}I){H}
\uput[40](H){$H$}
%
\psline(H)(H|0,0)(0,0)
\pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
\pspolygon(C)(D)(E)(F)
\pspolygon(E)(J)(I)(H)(G)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

What is the PSTricks equivalent for 'turn' in Tikz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following point construction to get the same behavior as  the TikZ's `turn` keyword does. The description is given as follows.

[image]

It is just one of four rarely-used point constructions in PSTricks. The remaining three are irrelevant for this question.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\def\a{3 }
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,PointName=none,linecolor=red](\pscalculate{4*\a},\pscalculate{2*\a})
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon]
                        ([nodesep=\pscalculate{1.5*\a},angle=90]O){A}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=-159]{O}A){B}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=120]{A}B){C}
    \pstGeonode
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=-125]{B}C){D}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=90]{C}D){E}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=90]{D}E){F}
    \pspolygon(C)(D)(E)(F)
    \pstGeonode
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=-37]{D}E){G}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=72]{E}G){H}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=72]{G}H){I}
                        ([nodesep=-\a,angle=72]{H}I){J}
    \pspolygon(E)(G)(H)(I)(J)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## An important note for PSTricks' maintainer:

- `angle=\pscalculate{180+90}` can be written as `angle={!180 90 add}`, but
- `nodesep=\pscalculate{1.5*\a}` cannot be written  as `nodesep={!1.5 \a mul}`

Answer (score 5):

With turtle graphics:

- `lt` : left,
- `rt` : right,
- `fd` : forward,
- `bk` : back,
- `pu` : pen up,
- `pd` : pen down

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-turtle}
\def\a{3 }
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](12,6)
\psTurtle[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt,linejoin=2]{turtle 0 setheading 
  90 lt \a 1.5 mul fd % first line
  159 rt \a fd 120 lt \a fd 120 lt \a fd % triangle
  pu \a bk pd % move
  115 lt \a fd 3 { 90 lt \a fd } repeat % square
  pu 90 lt \a fd 90 lt \a fd pd % move
  37 rt \a fd 4 { 72 lt \a fd } repeat % pentagon 
  pu 2 { 72 lt \a fd } repeat pd % move
  141 rt \a fd } % last line

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The package is not on CTAN (maybe next week), but available here:
http://latex.userpage.fu-berlin.de/pst-turtle.zip

It is also possible to rotate nodes with `\psRelNode`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\a{3 }
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linecolor=red](12,6)
  \pnodes(0,0){O}(!0 \a 1.5 mul){A}\uput[90](A){A}
  \psRelNode[angle=21](A)(O){0.667}{B}\uput[-90](B){B}
  \psRelNode[angle=60](A)(B){1}{C}\uput[90](C){C}
  \pspolygon[showpoints](A)(B)(C)

  \psRelNode[angle=145](C)(B){1}{D}\uput[90](D){D}
  \psRelNode[angle=90](D)(C){1}{E}\uput[-90](E){E}
  \psRelNode[angle=90](E)(D){1}{F}\uput[-90](F){F}
  \pspolygon[showpoints](C)(D)(E)(F)

  \psRelNode[angle=145](E)(F){1}{G}\uput[-90](G){G}
  \psRelNode[angle=-108](G)(E){1}{H}\uput[0](H){H}
  \psRelNode[angle=-108](H)(G){1}{I}\uput[0](I){I}
  \psRelNode[angle=-108](I)(H){1}{J}\uput[100](J){J}
  \pspolygon[showpoints](E)(G)(H)(I)(J)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your problem!